# Azure Traffic Manager Priority,Weighted and Performance

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I am generating some sample trying out business cases for Azure Traffic Manager along with different configuration like:

1. Performance

   2.Priority
2. Weighted

As per my understanding,
Performance can be used if I want to have minimal network latency for my Geo distributed application along with ensuring concept of localization.

Priority can be best utilized in case of fail over as If a node with High priority fails, traffic will be re-routed to the node with immediate low priority.

I am looking for a justifiable business case where I can use the weighted technique with the traffic manager.

Please correct me if I am going wrong with usage of Performance and Priority configuration and please help me understand the usage of weighted mode as well.

Thanks in advance to all the experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right about Performance and priority.
About the Weighted traffic-routing method, the 'Weighted' traffic-routing method allows you to distribute traffic evenly or to use a pre-defined weighting.
[image]
In the Weighted traffic-routing method, you assign a weight to each endpoint in the Traffic Manager profile configuration. The weight is an integer from 1 to 1000. This parameter is optional. If omitted, Traffic Managers uses a default weight of '1'.

More information about Weighted traffic-routing method, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#weighted-traffic-routing-method).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks Jason, That link was really useful.. I have browsed a lot but dont know how does it missed my eye :-)

Comment: An example of a specific use case our customers have used weighted round robin routing is when a new feature needs to be released in a phased manner. A customer could, for example, choose to make it available in only one endpoint and have say 1% of their users use it (by setting up the routing policy with this weightage) and can either roll it back or increase the percentage of users. hope this adds more context.